# How to run my application when another application starts

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to my application when another application starts up. Sounds confusing I know. Let me summarise it for you.

For Example:
When a game starts I want my application to open with it.

How would I go about doing this? Any ideas/methods would highly be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

I've tried searching for what I'm trying to do but unfortunately none of what I've found utilises what I want to do.

Comment: Write a shell script or create an alias that starts the application and your program at the same time, then use the script/alias as the launcher.

Comment: UI Automation, with an [AutomationEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationeventhandler) set to [WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.windowopenedevent). You'll be notified when any Windowed process (Console included) in the System is created. You, of course, need something that subscribes to the event.

Comment: You could have an active process in the tray notification area, which opens up the main program when an UI Automation event is raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to implement 'process interception'. You need a separate service that will continuously monitor the processes in Windows and intercepts if some kind of process is launched (the game in your example). That service then should start your application. If you search for 'process interception' you should find what you are looking for. Workspace management tools like RES can do this out of the box.